# p:fileupload how to set file name width?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Now I am using primefaces fileupload. I set width to fileupload. But when selecting long file names, filename is overflow. Like 
[image]

How to solve this??? My css is

```
.ui-panelgrid tr,.ui-panelgrid td {
    border: none;
}

.ui-fileupload .cancel {
    display: none;
}

.ui-fileupload .progress {
    display: none;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    color: #4F4F4F;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    width: 450px;
}

.fileupload-content {
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.fileupload-with {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: There's an atribute in `p:fileUpload` which is `allowTypes` it's a _regular expression_ to indicate what kind of files you are going to allow, but I would suggest you to go forward on this, although I've never used to limit files by filename, only extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to fix your CSS, has been asked many times on SO in general. Since you are using PF fileUpload particularly you can use something like this.

```
 .files td.name {
    word-break:break-all;
 }
```

More Info:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: Thank for your answer... I use .files td.name {
    word-break:break-all;
    width: 300px;
 }